# Displays the value but the result into an array

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to retrieve data from a database by using multiple where when I call on Views of data actually appears letters array? What is wrong?

Models

```
function produk() {
    $sql = "SELECT penjualan * jumlah FROM toko             
                WHERE toko = 'ALFA' AND produk = 'susu'";

       return $this->db->query($sql)->result();

}
```

Controllers

```
public function index() {
    $data=array('produk'        =>$this->m_ff->produk(),
                'isi'       =>'home/v_ff'
            );
    $this->load->view('layout/wrapper',$data);
}
```

Views

```
 <?php echo produk; ?>
```

Comment: Try adding a _label_ to the multiplication. `...SELECT (penjualan * jumlal) as result FROM ....`

Comment: thanks @ArnauLacambra , masih sama  result value = array,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you column name are correct

Need to change your query to

```
  SELECT * FROM toko             
            WHERE toko = 'ALFA' AND produk = 'susu'
```

If you want to multiply two colunm Using Active record then use it as

```
 $this->db->select("`penjualan`*`jumlah` as multiply", FAlSE);// for multiplication of two column
   $this->db->where("toko","ALFA");
   $this->db->where("produk","susu");
   $query=$this->db->get('toko');
   $ret = $query->row();// for single row
   return $ret->multiply;
```

And in `View` you get your data as

```
<?php echo $produk); ?>
```

Comment: thanks @Saty, i want cross value (value.penjualan * value.jumlah)

Comment: CHeck updated answer for multiplaction of two column

Comment: yes this result , Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [stockvalue] => 68000 ) ) , i want 68000 my result

Comment: For multiple data check https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html